# Form to Add Posts to Custom Post Type

Tags: theme-development

Basically I want to display a form on my blog (on a certain page) that will allow anyone to fill it out and it will create a post in a custom post type.

I saw the answer once before but I can't find it now.

Comment: I know you probably want to build this yourself, but I recently started working with a plugin called Formidable that does this really well. There's a free version, you may want to check it out. http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/formidable/

Comment: I tried formidable. But the free version have limitations. Date, time, hidden fields etc are locked.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

posting from the front-end is a matter of displaying a form and processing it:

form:

```
<!-- New Post Form -->
<div id="postbox">
<form id="new_post" name="new_post" method="post" action="">

<!-- post name -->
<p><label for="title">Title</label><br />
<input type="text" id="title" value="" tabindex="1" size="20" name="title" />
</p>

<!-- post Category -->
<p><label for="Category">Category:</label><br />
<p><?php wp_dropdown_categories( 'show_option_none=Category&tab_index=4&taxonomy=category' ); ?></p>


<!-- post Content -->
<p><label for="description">Content</label><br />
<textarea id="description" tabindex="3" name="description" cols="50" rows="6"></textarea>
</p>

<!-- post tags -->
<p><label for="post_tags">Tags:</label>
<input type="text" value="" tabindex="5" size="16" name="post_tags" id="post_tags" /></p>
<p align="right"><input type="submit" value="Publish" tabindex="6" id="submit" name="submit" /></p>

<input type="hidden" name="action" value="new_post" />
<?php wp_nonce_field( 'new-post' ); ?>
</form>
</div>
```

the processing:

```
if( 'POST' == $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] && !empty( $_POST['action'] ) &&  $_POST['action'] == "new_post") {

    // Do some minor form validation to make sure there is content
    if (isset ($_POST['title'])) {
        $title =  $_POST['title'];
    } else {
        echo 'Please enter a  title';
    }
    if (isset ($_POST['description'])) {
        $description = $_POST['description'];
    } else {
        echo 'Please enter the content';
    }
    $tags = $_POST['post_tags'];

    // Add the content of the form to $post as an array
    $new_post = array(
        'post_title'    => $title,
        'post_content'  => $description,
        'post_category' => array($_POST['cat']),  // Usable for custom taxonomies too
        'tags_input'    => array($tags),
        'post_status'   => 'publish',           // Choose: publish, preview, future, draft, etc.
        'post_type' => 'post_type_name'  //'post',page' or use a custom post type if you want to
    );
    //save the new post
    $pid = wp_insert_post($new_post); 
    //insert taxonomies
}
```

Comment: @Bainternet - Thanks, now is there a way to have the form redirect to the new post after they submit it?

Comment: yah wp_redirect(get_permalink($pid));  exit;

Comment: @Bainternet - Thanks again, but when i place that after the `wp_insert_post` function, I get an error that says cannot modify headers. Where do I put that?

Comment: wp_insert_post doesn't modify any headers or outputs any thing which leads me to think something is echoed out in you code, paste the exact code you are using so i'll get a better look

Comment: @Bainternet - http://pastebin.com/jTzryzAs

Comment: This is how you should laid out the code: http://pastebin.com/SRi2ZxWa

Comment: @Jared silent is right the processing part needs to come before the form

Comment: Hmm... kinda curious.  I've used every variation of a post form I can find.  Including this one.  I cannot get the validation portion to do anything......

Comment: how to add post_meta fields to this form?

Comment: @MohannadQamara you can use the following _after_ `$pid = wp_insert_post($new_post);`-- `if( $pid ) { add_post_meta( $pid, 'post_meta_name', 'post meta value' ); }`

Comment: @Bainternet what about applying terms to a specific taxonomy for the custom post type?

Comment: @Anagio consider [Asking new question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) and referencing this one.

Comment: @Bainternet will do that tomorrow once I can post some sample code so I can show I've tried something. Found a few tutorials. If I have no luck i'll post.

Answer (score 1):

It might be simpler to use a plugin to do this.

You could also use the excellent [Contact Form 7](https://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7/) plugin along with the [Post My CF7 Form extension](https://wordpress.org/plugins/post-my-contact-form-7/) plugin which will allow you to save any custom forms to a custom post, including images as featured attachments, custom meta fields and select/checkbox/radio inputs as taxonomies.

The Post My CF7 Form plugin has a rich functionality that can be leveraged to further customise and tweak the way your forms should be saved.  There is a detailed [documentation section](https://wordpress.org/plugins/post-my-contact-form-7/other_notes/) too.

Comment: you should mention that you're the creator of the plugin.