# Form to Add Posts to Custom Post Type (Again)

Tags: theme-development

I pretty much got my answer in my last question, but not quite. I was supposed to add one last code to my source and it would have worked but the person helping hasn't replied now and I don't know what to do :S

[Form to Add Posts to Custom Post Type](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/11288/form-to-add-posts-to-custom-post-type)

So can anybody tell me where to put `wp_redirect(get_permalink($pid)); exit;` in my code to have it redirect to the post after the post is added to the database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put the form processing part of the code at the top of the page before anything else and

```
wp_redirect(get_permalink($pid)); exit;
```

Right after

```
$pid = wp_insert_post($new_post);
```

Comment: I'm still getting a headers error, this is what it says: `Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\qa\header.php:6) in C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-includes\pluggable.php on line 897`

Comment: whats the code you are using?

Comment: also try replacing exit; with die();

Comment: I'm getting the same error, using the exact same code in my last question you told me to use and added the code just below `$pid = wp_insert_post($new_post);` like above and also tried switching it with die() and I get the same problem. It's pretty strange!

Comment: its beacuse you use "get_header" before the processing part of the code look at http://pastie.org/1651163 i fixed it and added a better error handeling

Answer (score 0):

You can add it on your processing section:

```
if( 'POST' == $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] && !empty( $_POST['action'] ) &&  $_POST['action'] == "new_post") {
```

Just below:

```
$pid = wp_insert_post($new_post);
```

Make it something like this:

```
$pid = wp_insert_post($new_post);
wp_redirect(get_permalink($pid)); exit;
```

**EDIT:**
Oops, after reading comment on that page, seems like you put it in wrong style. See my comment on that page.

If you don't want to change current code, you can use something like this:

```
$pid = wp_insert_post($new_post);
?><script type="text/javascript">
<!--
window.location = "<?php echo get_permalink($pid); ?>";
//-->
</script><?php
```