# need to add attach thumbnail from my form

Tags: forms, thumbnails

i need to add [attach thumbnail] to this form

functions.php Code:

```
if( 'POST' == $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] && !empty( $_POST['action'] ) &&  $_POST['action'] == "new_post") {

    // Do some minor form validation to make sure there is content
    $title =  $_POST['title'];
    $ordertype = $_POST['ordertype'];
    $price = $_POST['price'];
    $ordertime = $_POST['ordertime'];

    // Add the content of the form to $post as an array
    $new_post = array(
        'post_title'    => $title,
        'post_content'  => $description,
        'post_category' => array($_POST['category']),
        'post_status'   => 'publish',
        'post_type' => 'post'
    );
    //save the new post
    $pid = wp_insert_post($new_post); 
    add_post_meta($pid, 'ordertype', $ordertype, true);
    add_post_meta($pid, 'price', $price, true);
    add_post_meta($pid, 'ordertime', $ordertime, true);
    wp_redirect('/'); exit;
    //insert taxonomies
}
```

source: [Form to Add Posts to Custom Post Type](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/11288/form-to-add-posts-to-custom-post-type/11289#comment48726_11289)

Answer (score 1):

Its pretty simple actually. Here is the link for the set_thumbnail function reference [codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/set_post_thumbnail). And here is the answer for the [file upload](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/42068/handling-front-end-file-uploads-considering-safety-and-ease-of-use/42372#42372).

First off all you have to attach the file to the post :

```
function attach_uploads($uploads,$post_id = 0){
$files = rearrange($uploads);
if($files[0]['name']==''){
    return false;   
}
foreach($files as $file){
    $upload_file = wp_handle_upload( $file, array('test_form' => false) );
    $attachment = array(
    'post_mime_type' => $upload_file['type'],
    'post_title' => preg_replace('/\.[^.]+$/', '', basename($upload_file['file'])),
    'post_content' => '',
    'post_status' => 'inherit'
);
    $attach_id = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, $upload_file['file'], $post_id );
    $attach_array[] = $attach_id;
    require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php');
    $attach_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $upload_file['file'] );
    wp_update_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $attach_data );
}
return $attach_array;
}
```

More detail about the php file upload rearrangement : [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.multiple.php).

And this is the function to set the uploaded file as post thumbnail. Put it in the corresponding wp_ajax function.

```
// put this one early, before any process
$files = $_FILES['profile-picture'];

// insert attachment, after you have the new post id of course
$attached_files = attach_uploads($files,$pid);

// set the first file as post thumbnail
// $attached_files[0] is for the first file

if($attached_files){
    set_post_thumbnail( $pid, $attached_files[0] ); 
}
```

Hope this help

**ADDED :**

```
function rearrange( $arr ){
    foreach( $arr as $key => $all ){
        foreach( $all as $i => $val ){
            $new[$i][$key] = $val;    
        }    
    }
    return $new;
}
```

Just put it in the functions.php

Comment: i add first code in functions.php, but another codes i don`t know how can i use it..!

Comment: i add my source code in functions.php before your code.. how can i add your code to mine?

Comment: Both of them should be in the functions.php. Put this `$files = $_FILES['profile-picture'];` after `$ordertime = $_POST['ordertime'];` and put the rest `add_post_meta($pid, 'ordertime', $ordertime, true);`

Comment: can you check my new answer?

Answer (score 0):

thanks @ifdion ..
That is my finally functions.php code

```
if( 'POST' == $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] && !empty( $_POST['action'] ) &&  $_POST['action'] == "new_post") {

    // Do some minor form validation to make sure there is content
    $title =  $_POST['title'];
    $ordertype = $_POST['ordertype'];
    $price = $_POST['price'];
    $ordertime = $_POST['ordertime'];
    $files = $_FILES['profile-picture'];

    // Add the content of the form to $post as an array
    $new_post = array(
        'post_title'    => $title,
        'post_content'  => $description,
        'post_category' => array($_POST['category']),  // Usable for custom taxonomies too
        'post_status'   => 'publish',           // Choose: publish, preview, future, draft, etc.
        'post_type' => 'post'  //'post',page' or use a custom post type if you want to
    );
    //save the new post
    $pid = wp_insert_post($new_post); 
    add_post_meta($pid, 'ordertype', $ordertype, true);
    add_post_meta($pid, 'price', $price, true);
    add_post_meta($pid, 'ordertime', $ordertime, true);
    $attached_files = attach_uploads($files,$pid);
    if($attached_files){
    set_post_thumbnail( $pid, $attached_files[0] ); 
    }
    wp_redirect(get_permalink($pid)); exit;
    //insert taxonomies
}
function attach_uploads($uploads,$post_id = 0){
    $files = rearrange($uploads);
    if($files[0]['name']==''){
        return false;   
    }
    foreach($files as $file){
        $upload_file = wp_handle_upload( $file, array('test_form' => false) );
        $attachment = array(
        'post_mime_type' => $upload_file['type'],
        'post_title' => preg_replace('/\.[^.]+$/', '', basename($upload_file['file'])),
        'post_content' => '',
        'post_status' => 'inherit'
    );
        $attach_id = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, $upload_file['file'], $post_id );
        $attach_array[] = $attach_id;
        require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php');
        $attach_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $upload_file['file'] );
        wp_update_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $attach_data );
    }
    return $attach_array;
}
```

and this upload [input] in theme..

```
<input type="file" id="profile-picture" name="profile-picture[]" size="40" multiple />
```

but if i do submit for form, responding with this error...

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function rearrange()

sorry for your time

Comment: here is the link for the rearrange function [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.multiple.php). do give it a try

Comment: MR @ifdion, I try it, really i can`t do it :(

Comment: can you give more detail? is there any error message? have you put the rearrange() function?

Comment: yeah, same error message [Fatal error: Call to undefined function rearrange()]

Comment: have you put the `rearrange()` function? the one on my added answer?

Comment: yes i do, check again my top code..

Comment: you called the function on `$files = rearrange($uploads);`, but did you declare the function itself?