# Form to custom post type and custom taxonomy

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

I am actually learning still. so if my question sounds a bit silly. kindly pardon me. 
But I seriously need help here. 
Using the links below, I managed to get the form working to the extent that it posts the submissions to custom post type "Trademen" but I am unable to get the form capture the custom taxonomy "trademan-industry"

[Form to Add Posts to Custom Post Type](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/11288/form-to-add-posts-to-custom-post-type)

The code I am using form the above link is here. http://pastebin.com/FPEFrd4p

Your help will be greatly appreciated and overcome my frustration.

Comment: Paste your code in your question please

Answer (score 0):

Use [WP set object terms](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_set_object_terms)

```
$new_post = array(
        'post_title'    => $title,
        'post_content'  => $description,
        'tags_input'    => array($tags),
        'post_address'    => array($address),
        'post_status'   => 'draft',           // Choose: publish, preview, future, draft, etc.
        'post_type' => 'trademen'  //'post',page' or use a custom post type if you want to
);
//save the new post
$pid = wp_insert_post($new_post);
 wp_set_object_terms( $pid, $industry, 'trademan-industry' );
```

Comment: really thanks. It worked like charm. Could you also tell me
1- if I want to add one more custom taxonomy $tcategory,'trademan-category'. How would that be done
2- How can I go about letting users submit an image as well
3- sorry one last thing. what would I do if I were to add a ACF field address
really thanks for your help

Comment: @Sab try [this link](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/01/create-custom-taxonomies-wordpress/) to create taxanomy. And for image upload use [this](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/11920/submit-post-and-upload-image-from-front-end)

Comment: and for acf fields you can use [this](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_post_meta) after the wp_insert_post

Comment: thanks for your response. Sorry for being pain. not sure why it seems so gibberish. I need to add another taxonomy, image, and acf field in the same context. I tried to add these here http://pastebin.com/LqV6s1Gx (updated) but having trouble making sense in the code. I'd need bit more details wrt solution you suggested.
secondly could you point me to some learning resource which is geared towards beginners. (Lynda's got only few though to cover coding aspect)

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve this is to use [Contact Form 7](https://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7/) form plugin and the extension plugin [Post My CF7 Form](https://wordpress.org/plugins/post-my-contact-form-7/). It allows you to map your entire form submission to a custom post.
It also allows you to map custom taxonomies to the form fields as dropdown, checkbox or radio buttons.
There is an extensive documention on the plugin extension page.